# Lightning Component not showing in Community App Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder

I have a component that is not showing on Community Builder.My managed package app has a component and one of our customers has an issue where we cannot see the Lightning Component in the Community Builder >> Custom Components. I am wondering if that could be permission?

Here are the things that I have verified.

1 -  In the component I have set forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="XXXComponentController" >
```

2 - The Customer has deployed the Domain to users.

3 - We can see other components on Community Builder >> Custom Components(Those components are all created manually not from managed package).

4 -  If I install the same app version in a new org, I can see the component.

My questions are:
1 - Is there any Permission Set that I need to set?
2 - Is there anything else I could check?
3 - If I enable the Debug mode, which information I should look for in the console?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new version and I pushed to the customer again, and seems to solve the issue, somehow it shows the component in his org. Thank you for all the answers.

**Updated on: 2019-09-27** 
Another way to solve this issue is to compile all the Apex classes.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see missing is number three here. ([Configure Components for Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm))

"3. Add a Design Resource to Your Component Bundle"

Other than that your description sounds about right and I can't think of anything else without looking at it.

Comment: Thank you for answering, yes, I have the Design Resource. =) This component shows fine in my test org, dev org, my test enterprise hub org.

Answer (score 1):

**Have you make your Component as Global Component**? If you want your component to be visible in managed package org then you need to make component global.

```
<aura:component access="global">
```

Comment: Hi Manjot, thanks for answering, yes, I have that.